# Assembly on DOS (TASM), creating TSR with a new handler on int 21h

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm, tsr

I have a trouble with making TSR com file for DOS. It should set a new handler on a 21'th interrupt, terminate and stay resident. New handler should transfer control to an old interrupt 21h handler. I save its interrupt vector, but have no idea how to call it correctly. Here is a program:

```
.model tiny
.data
    old_int21h dw ?, ?
.code
org 100h
start:

    ;saving old interrupt vector
    mov ax, 3521h
    int 21h
    mov [old_int21h], bx
    mov [old_int21h + 2], es

    ;setting new interrupt vector
    cli
    push ds
    push cs
    pop ds
    lea dx, myint21h
    mov ax, 2521h
    int 21h
    pop ds
    sti

    ; TSR
    lea dx, start
    int 27h

myint21h proc
    ; doing something
    ; want to transfer control to an old interrupt 21h handler here. How?
    iret
myint21h endp

end start
```

Comment: Which version of DOS?

Comment: Using dosbox with DOS v.5.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood the problem. The right solution is here. "Right" isn't sure "optimal", but works nice anyway, and it isn't hard enough to optimize this code now.

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h
start:

    ; saving old interrupt vector
    mov ax, 3521h
    int 21h
    mov [old_int21h], bx
    mov [old_int21h + 2], es

    ; setting new interrupt vector
    cli
    push ds
    push cs
    pop ds
    lea dx, myint21h
    mov ax, 2521h
    int 21h
    pop ds
    sti

    ; TSR
    mov dx, 00ffh
    mov ax, 3100h
    int 21h

    ; here comes data & hew handler part
    old_int21h dw ?, ?

    myint21h proc
                    ; some stuff
                    ; transfer control to an old interrupt 21h handler
        push word ptr [cs:old_int21h + 2] ; segment
        push word ptr [cs:old_int21h]     ; offset
        retf
    myint21h endp

end start
```

The answer below was almost right :)

Answer (score 2):

My 16-bit DOS ASM is a bit rusty, but if I recall correctly you need to do this:

```
push word ptr [old_int21h + 2] ; segment
push word ptr [old_int21h]     ; offset
retf
```

Comment: Note that this is a jump to the old handler - control does not return to your hook but directly to the original caller (if you kept the stack intact - if not it will probably just blow up instead :)

Comment: Is it working on your DOS? When I use this, dosbox freezes after first int 21h. Is my program correct in general? Stack is kept intact.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't actually have a working environment at my disposal that I could do 16-bit DOS development on. Back when I did DOS ISR/TSR work, and I have, I had things like SoftICE at my disposal to aid when things went south, which they often did - this stuff is not easy to get right.

Answer (score -1):

```
     .model tiny
     .code
     org 100h
     start:

; Inicializando la fecha para LotusWorks
    mov ax, 2A21h
    int 21h
    mov [Reg_DX], dx
        sub cx,064h
    mov [Reg_CX], cx

; saving old interrupt vector
    mov ax, 3521h
    int 21h
    mov [old_int21h], bx
    mov [old_int21h + 2], es

; setting new interrupt vector

    cli
    push ds
    push cs
    pop ds
    lea dx, myint21h
    mov ax, 2521h
    int 21h
    pop ds
    sti

     ; TSR
    mov dx, 00ffh
    mov ax, 3100h
    int 21h

     ; here comes data & hew handler part

    old_int21h dw ?, ?
    Reg_DX     dw ?, ?
    Reg_CX     dw ?, ?

     myint21h proc

       cmp ah,2ah
       jne S1
           cmp al,56h
           je  S2
           mov ah,02h
           int 01AH
           cmp cx,0
           jne Mismodia
           mov ax,02A56h
           int 21h
      mov [CS:Reg_DX], dx

MismoDia:
       mov cx, [cs:Reg_CX]
       mov al,00
       mov dx, [cs:Reg_DX]
       iret

       S2:
           mov al,0

       S1:
        ; transfer control to an old
        ; interrupt 21h handler


        push word ptr [cs:old_int21h + 2]   ; segment
        push word ptr [cs:old_int21h]       ; offset
        retf
    myint21h endp

     end start
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.